# How can I prevent SQL to allocate same uniqueidentifier on the same table?

Tags: sql-server, guid, uniqueidentifier

I am wondering how does SQL Server ensure that `uniqueidentifier` values remain unique within a table?

Of course I can make that field a unique key but that's not the issue.

Comment: [GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx)

Comment: The chance of a duplicate Guid value is 1 in 2^128, Almost Never, If you ask a mathematician he will argue with the word NEVER as there is a probability of a duplicate :) a good read have a look here [`The Quick Guide to GUIDs`](http://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/)